# Delphi: Extract resources under Android

Tags: android, delphi

I'm about to port a Delphi Windows app to Android, for the first time ever, so please forgive if the question is stupid.

The app has an embedded database file (well, technically, it's jus an Excel workbook, but that's not the main problem). The problem is that the previous code

```
var
ResStream: TResourceStream;
begin
ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(HINSTANCE, 'ID_GCDB', RT_RCDATA);
...
end;
```

does not compile. RT_RCDATA is defined in the unit Windows which the mobile compiler, not exactly surprising, never heard of. Is there a way to extract resources in Delphi under Android and if yes, is there portable way to do that, meaning one that just works on Android and Windows?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resource_Files_Support

Comment: How can I mark your post as the answer? Because that absolutely helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resource_Files_Support) explains what you need to do:

> Resource files are only supported for desktop platforms. In mobile platforms, the OS does not accept loading from resource files. To load files to a mobile device use a different approach, by loading the files externally.

The same documentation topic linked to above then gives step by step details of how to use the deployment manager to make sure your assets are deployed with your app. The documentation topic then goes on to provide a simple code sample demonstrating how to locate the assets.

Answer (score 0):

With Delphi 11.3, I was able to use the resources as usual in an Android-32 application - no special handling was required.

Comment: What was your process ?

Comment: @LegitLearner: I opened "Project"->"Resources" and added the files in the resource panel.